# Nestjs query OR

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

why isn't this part of code working, I mean, it throws an "invalid string length" error:

```
  if(carBrand == 'Ferrari or Porsche')  {
    query = query.andWhere(`db_table.carBrand = :tmp_1 OR db_table.contentLevel = :tmp_2`, {
      tmp_1: `Ferrari`,
      tmp_2: `Porsche`,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, this would be the solution:

```
query = query.andWhere(
  "(db_table.carBrand = 'Ferrari' OR db_table.carBrand = 'Porsche')", 
);
```